# Will villagers die if there are more villagers than beds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm living inside a village, and because I bred some villagers, there are more villagers than beds.

I tried to build walls around the village, and put torches inside the wall, but some mobs do spawn or they get in from somewhere.

So will the villagers die from mobs if I leave the village to do something else, since they won't go inside as they have no bed?

I could get more beds but sheep are pretty far away from where I live and I have no lead.

Comment: Are you sure they are dying and not just despawning or falling outside a chunk border?

Comment: @pinckerman they haven't died or despawned as of yet, just worried in the future as I'll keep breeding villagers.

Comment: try to mob-proof better then, see where the mobs are coming from and put torches to prevent spawning. endermen can still teleport, but won't hurt villagers afaik. and if you are far away and the village is not in spawn chunks, pretty sure mobs won't spawn there anyways.

Comment: @Esther yeah I did put so many torches there, just having hard time seeing where the mobs are coming from

Comment: I mean, if the indoors are lit up and all the villagers are trapped inside, mobs can't touch them.